# Ruby on Rails batch processing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sidekiq

I am working on a Rails app that runs regularly scheduled sidekiq jobs, and I understand how queues and background jobs works. I'm working with a 3rd party that requests that I batch jobs to them so that each worker handles one job at a time with 50 workers running in parallel.

I've been researching this for hours, but I'm unclear on how to do this and how to tell if it's actually working. Currently, my procfile looks like this:

`web: bundle exec unicorn -p $PORT -c ./config/unicorn.rb
worker: bundle exec sidekiq -C ./config/sidekiq.yml`

Is it as simple as increasing the concurrency from the rake task to `-c 50` in the worker line? Or do I need to use `ConnectionPool` inside the worker class? The Rails docs say that using `find_each` is "useful if you want multiple workers dealing with the same processing queue." If I run `find_each` inside the rake task and call the worker once for each item, will it run the jobs in parallel? I read one article that says that concurrency and parallelism are often confused, so I am, in turn, a little confused about which direction to take.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure, but you may to look at Sidekiq Superworker https://github.com/socialpandas/sidekiq-superworker#batch-jobs

Comment: I think 'find_each' and calling the worker once for each inside the block can solve your problem.